# is the c# compiler exentisble?

Tags: c#, compiler-construction

Is there any way to add your own language extension?

For example make it so:

```
public string Foo { get; set; }
```

can be coded as:

```
public auto string Foo;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, but you can just type

```
prop
```

in Visual Studio, press Tab (maybe twice), and voilà! You get what you wanted. :D

Answer (score 3):

Nope - you can't extend the C# compiler in this way.

You should be thankful it's that short, you used to have to write:

```
public string Foo
{
    get
    {
        return this.foo;
    }
    set
    {
        this.foo = value;
    }
}
private string foo;
```